# Prevent http.handleFunc("/", func(w, r) { }) handler being called for all unmatched requests

Tags: go

Consider the below very basic HTTP server code, started in the `main()` function by calling `run()` with an argument, where the argument is intended to specify a root directory path.

```golang
package main

import "fmt"
import "net/http"
import "strings"

func main() {
    // run("/")              // option 1
    // run("/newbase")       // option 2
}

func run(basePath string) {
    var path = fmt.Sprintf("%s", basePath)
    if !strings.HasPrefix(path, "/") {
        path = fmt.Sprintf("/%s", path)
    }
    if !strings.HasSuffix(path, "/") {
        path = fmt.Sprintf("%s/", path)
    }

    http.HandleFunc(fmt.Sprintf("%sfoo", path), handleFoo)
    http.HandleFunc(fmt.Sprintf("%sbar", path), handleBar)
    http.HandleFunc(fmt.Sprintf("%s", path), handleRoot)

    http.ListenAndServe(":60001", nil)
}

func handleRoot(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprint(w, "Root")
}
func handleFoo(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprint(w, "Foo")
}
func handleBar(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprint(w, "Bar")
}
```

If `run("/")` is called, the server should respond to the URLs */*, */foo* and */bar*.

If `run("/newbase")` is called, the server should respond to the URLs */newbase/*, */newbase/foo* and */newbase/bar*.

I would like for any other URL to return the standard HTTP/404, but it appears that the */* handler is called for unhandled child paths.  This leads to a weird difference in behaviour where:

```
                  | For run("/")                    | For run("/newbase")
Entered URL       |---------------------------------+---------------------------------
                  | Desired        | Actual         | Desired        | Actual
------------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------
 /                | HTTP/200 Root  | HTTP/200 Root  | HTTP/404       | HTTP/404
------------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------
 /foo             | HTTP/200 Foo   | HTTP/200 Foo   | HTTP/404       | HTTP/404
------------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------
 /foo/qux         | HTTP/404       | HTTP/200 Root  | HTTP/404       | HTTP/404
------------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------
 /bar             | HTTP/200 Bar   | HTTP/200 Bar   | HTTP/404       | HTTP/404
------------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------
 /baz             | HTTP/404       | HTTP/200 Root  | HTTP/404       | HTTP/404
------------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------
 /newbase         | HTTP/404       | HTTP/200 Root  | HTTP/200 Root  | HTTP/200 Root
------------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------
 /newbase/foo     | HTTP/404       | HTTP/200 Root  | HTTP/200 Foo   | HTTP/200 Foo
------------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------
 /newbase/foo/qux | HTTP/404       | HTTP/200 Root  | HTTP/404       | HTTP/200 Root
------------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------
 /newbase/bar     | HTTP/404       | HTTP/200 Root  | HTTP/200 Bar   | HTTP/200 Bar
------------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------
 /newbase/baz     | HTTP/404       | HTTP/200 Root  | HTTP/404       | HTTP/200 Root
```

I assume this happens because the first argument to `http.HandleFunc` is treated as a pattern for closest match, rather than an exact match.

Is there any way to force the handlers to require an exact (preferably case-insensitive) match, so that it doesn't serve the */* handler for unregistered URLs and instead responds with the default HTTP/404?

```
# go version
go version go1.14.9 linux/amd64
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [http.ServeMux documentation](https://godoc.org/net/http#ServeMux) says:

> Patterns name fixed, rooted paths, like "/favicon.ico", or rooted subtrees, like "/images/" (note the trailing slash).

and

> Note that since a pattern ending in a slash names a rooted subtree, the pattern "/" matches all paths not matched by other registered patterns, not just the URL with Path == "/".

To handle an exact match on `/` (or any other pattern ending with  `/`), add code to the handler to respond with 404 if the path is not equal to the pattern. Use [http.NotFound](https://godoc.org/net/http#NotFound) to respond with the "default" 404 response.

```
http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if r.URL.Path != "/" {
        http.NotFound(w, r)
        return
    }
    // code to handle / here
})
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because [`http.ServeMux`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ServeMux) does a prefix based matching.

A pattern ending in a slash names a rooted subtree, the pattern "/" matches all paths not matched by other registered patterns, not just the URL with Path == "/".

So if you want an exact path based matching, one way to achieve your goal is to change this part

```
    http.HandleFunc(fmt.Sprintf("%sfoo", path), handleFoo)
    http.HandleFunc(fmt.Sprintf("%sbar", path), handleBar)
    http.HandleFunc(fmt.Sprintf("%s", path), handleRoot)
```

to this:

```
    http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
        switch r.URL.Path {
        case fmt.Sprintf("%sfoo", path):
            handleFoo(w, r)
        case fmt.Sprintf("%sbar", path):
            handleBar(w, r)
        case fmt.Sprintf("%s", path):
            handleRoot(w, r)
        default:
            http.NotFoundHandler().ServeHTTP(w, r)
        }
    })
```

Comment: Because the %sfoo and %sbar do not end with /, there's no difference between registering separate handlers in the first snippet and comparing the paths in the second snippet (except for performance).